# {"errorMessages":["Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): expected a valid value

Tags: json, windows, rest, curl, jira

I found "Query using POST" from [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-query-issues).

And tried to use curl command from command like. Installed curl by refering [this](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203691436-Installing-and-using-cURL) for windows.

Here is my CURL string:

```
curl -D- -u admin:password -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data 
'{"jql":"project = CI","startAt":0,"maxResults":50,"fields":["summary","status","assignee"]}' 
"https://myclientname.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search"
```

This is how I'm doing and getting error:

```
{"errorMessages":["Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): expected a valid value
(number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n
at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@1626cb2; line: 1, column: 2]"]}
```

Is there any problem making this curl string in windows? Please suggest? How can I correct this and get JSON object? Please note that, userID, password and client name is correct. Thanks.

Comment: I just changed like this : curl -D- -u admin:password -X POST -H """Content-Type: application/json""" --data "{"""jql""":"""project = CI""","""startAt""":0,"""maxResults""":50,"""fields""":["""id""","""key"""]}" """https://myclientname.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search"""   Its saying: curl: (6) Could not resolve host: =
curl: (3) [globbing] bad range specification in column 43
curl: (1) Protocol ""https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Comment: Based on your comment, and just as an experiment to get more information about the problem, try again without using HTTPS. In other words, use `"http://myclientname.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search"` instead of `"https://myclientname.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search"`.

Comment: Did you get any luck on this? I got the same issue.

Answer (score 42):

Seems to be an windows issue. Do not use the `'` (single-quote) character.

Instead, use `"` (double-quote) character for enclosing the string. Then, if you have inner quotes, use `"""` (3x double-quotes) to escape them.

Example: `"{ """name""":"""Frodo""", """age""":123 }"`

Comment: You can shorten this by using \" instead of """

Comment: Worked like a charm. I was having same issue. That command with single `"` works well in Linux Machine but it shows error in Windows. Using 3 `"` worked perfectly.

Comment: Just use Git Bash

Answer (score 2):

I tried the cURL you pointed to in your question, but with no luck. Also, the cURL comes with Git is not working either. However, the one I installed with CygWin works. And the same command is also working in Ubuntu. Which basically indicates that your command itself is OK.

If you are working on Windows, I recommend you to use a tool called [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). It can perform almost all HTTP requests you may need. Good luck!

**Update:**
Here I add the steps to make HTTP POST request with Fiddler.

1) After starting Fiddler, you will see the GUI like Figure 1. The upper right panel is where you should input staff like JIRA's website, request type, and the content you want to post. To be specific, under the "Composer" tab, you need to select "POST" as your request type, and put the JIRA's URL there, keep HTTP/1.1 selected. You should put the request header under the URL bar. *Now, you need to pay attention to*. At least, you should input two things in HTTP header: the *content type*, which is "application/json", and the *authorization header*. The authentication is a Base64 string, you can get your Base64 string [here](https://www.base64decode.org/) with your "admin:password". If you want to know more about the basic authentication method, please refer Jira's website [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-basic-authentication). The lower right panel of the GUI is where you should put your post content.
[image]

2) When you get these staff ready, you can click the "Execute" button at upper right corner of the GUI. The execution result will be shown at the left panel. As Figure 2 shows, if you get a result with the status 200, congratulations, you got it. If you get other types of results, please google the error code or leave comments here. 
[image]

3) Double click the result, the returned JSON content will be shown in the lower right panel like Figure 3. You can try different tab to see the returned staff. For example, if you go to the "TextView", you will get the returned JSON as pure string.
[image]

Please comment if you have any further question.

Comment: I'm very new to this Fiddler. Any step by step guide , how to use this in this case?

Comment: Hi, here is a post that shows you how to use Fiddler with pictures. http://www.asjava.com/tools/fiddler-tutorial-how-to-use-fiddler/. Fiddler is very good, my team and I use it everyday. Hope it helps.

Comment: What is the steps to make this curl request using Fiddler? Please edit your answer with the steps.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```sh
curl.exe -u elastic:Password! -k -X POST "https://localhost:9200/_security/user/kibana_system/_password?pretty" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"""password""" : """CHANGEME"""}'
```

Notice the format of the last parameter (`--data`): it uses single quotes (`'`) as string delimiters and triple double-quotes (`"`) inside)

Answer (score 0):

Pls verify if you have any value wrapped with single quote.

e.g

```
"NetworkType": 'Test'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should work.

```sh
curl -D- -u admin:password -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data 
\\"{"jql":"project = CI","startAt":0,"maxResults":50,"fields":["summary","status","assignee"]}\\"
"https://myclientname.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search"
```

Don't forget to use a slash (\*{}\*}after and before json

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, when running CURL:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
     -X POST --data "{\"field1\":\"value1\",\"field2\":\"value2\"}" http://localhost:8080/app/endpoint
```

In other words escape double quotes for the fields/values with `\"`